# Difference between "scordare" and "dimenticare"

Tags: word-choice, difference

When do you suggest to use "dimenticare" and when "scordare"? Is "dimenticare" only for reasonings or also valid for people?

E.g.

> Avevo dimenticato il tuo viso
>
> Avevo scordato il tuo viso

Secondo voi?

Comment: Doesn't the fact that scordare is the opposite of ricordare (to remember) come into this discussion? Also, wouldn't it be more correct to refer to these verb infinitives as reflexive (i.e. scordarsi)?

Comment: @davidino: As for your second remark: no, both *scordare* and *dimenticare* can be used both as transitive verbs (*Ho dimenticato/scordato l'asciugamano a casa*) and reflexive ones (*Mi sono dimenticato/scordato di avvertire Gigi*).

Comment: There's an interesting discussion about 'scordare' and 'dimenticare' at [Word Reference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/scordare-vs-dimenticare.421389/) also.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, they have the same meaning and both could be used in your examples.
Nonetheless, there is a little difference in the meaning due to their Latin origins.

- *dimenticare* comes from the word *mens, mentis* (mind) with the prefix *de-* (distance). To forget something would be *to get it out of one's mind*.
- *scordare* comes from the word *cor* (heart) with the prefix *s-* (meaning again distance or cancellation). To forget something would be *to get it out of one's heart*.

That's why you can say *ho dimenticato/scordato il tuo viso* but you would usually say *il primo amore non si scorda mai*.

Comment: Just for clarity, _mentis_ and _cor_ are Latin words. I think you shouldn't say "you can only say..." when you mention that sentence, it is a well-known saying that goes like that, and there is this reason about the heart behind the usage of _scordare_ there, but it wouldn't be grammatically wrong to use _dimenticare_.

Comment: @martina I said exactly about their Latin origin, didn't I? Regarding the saying, yes, _dimenticare_ could be grammatically correct but nobody would say it this way and I've been trying to explain why.

Comment: ok, that wasn't a criticism. As for the Latin, sorry, I didn't notice. As for the sentence, I just wanted to remark that it's a fixed saying.

Comment: @TheycallmeTrinity On forums and facebook? Do we really want to appeal to the facebook users as a reference? :) Again: I've never said that it would be grammatically incorrect. I explained _the reasons why_ this saying is originally constructed and used with the verb _scordare_ rather than _dimenticare_. Fin qui siamo d'accordo? :)

Comment: @TheycallmeTrinity OK, thanks. I take your arguments and I've edited the answer. Nonetheless, I would never use _dimenticare_ in that sentence myself. Not only because it's a fixed saying, as martina said in her comment above, but because of its meaning: you can actually forget your first love (_dimenticare_), you may even not think about it for years, but you can never fully get it out from the depths of your heart (_scordare_).

Answer (score 6):

You can use them both interchangeably, they basically mean the same thing, although *scordare* may also be referred to an instrument that is out of tune.

Despite the fact that people believe *scodare* is less formal than *dimenticare*, it is not in fact exclusively part of any regional vocabulary and each region applies its own peculiarities to this verb when in use.

For further reading on this matter, please [refer to this page](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/scordare-dimenticare) on the [Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it) website.

Answer (score 1):

When I was a kid, my teacher would correct "scordare" by saying "you are not a guitar". The joke was that "scordare" sounds like the opposite of "accordare" (to tune). Because of this early imprinting, I tend to use "*dimenticare*" but I noticed that "*scordare*" is being used more and more in everyday Italian.